# summation inequality with logarithms

Tags: inequality, induction, asymptotics

show:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \log_{2}\,i = O(n\log n)$$

Proof by induction:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \log\,i \le n\log n$$

$$\text{Test for n=1:  }\sum_{i=1}^1 \log_{2}\,i \le 1\log 1$$
$$0 \le 0\text{ true for }n=1$$

Assume true for $n=k$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \log\,i \le k\log k$$

Prove true for $n =k+1$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \log\,i \le (k+1)\log(k+1)$$

By assumption:
$$\log 1 + \log 2 + \ldots + \log k \le k\log k$$

then add the extra $k+1$ term:
$$\log 1 + \log 2 + \ldots + \log k + \log(k+1) \le k\log k + \log(k+1)$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \log i \le k\log k + \log(k+1)$$

***Not sure how to show: $k\log k + \log(k+1) \lt (k+1)\log(k+1)$*** 
(this shows by the transitivity of $\lt$ that the statement is also true for $n =k+1$)

therefore:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \log\,i \le (k+1)\log(k+1)$$

Extra:
In original problem I see that they had $\log$ to the base $2$ on the left hand side but not on the right hand side. I chose to drop the base but not sure if this was a correct decision.

Comment: Can't you just say that $\log(k) < \log(k+1)$ and thus $k\log(k)+\log(k+1)<k\log(k+1)+\log(k+1)=(k+1)\log(k+1)$

Comment: I guess I could and will look into this suggestion as well.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question as-stated does not say to do induction, I'll do an easier way, since it seems likely you only are doing it that way because you think it best.

$1$) Note $\log_2 x={1\over \log 2}\log x$ by the change of base formula.

$2$) Note that $\log x$ is an increasing function, hence $0<x\le y\iff \log x\le \log y$ and so

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\log_2 i={1\over\log 2}\sum_{i=1}^n\log i\le {1\over \log 2}\sum_{i=1}^n\log n= Cn\log n$$

which completes the proof.

Insofar as your original one goes, if you want to show

$$k\log k+\log(k+1)\le (k+1)\log(k+1)$$

it's not bad, you just use the monotonicity property I noted in ($2$) to see that $k\log k< k\log(k+1)$ and you're done.

Comment: I chose to do the proof by induction since I'm still trying to wrap my head around the concept itself. Yes I can see that klogk is < (k+1)log(k+1) but the LHS has the extra term of log(k+1) and was confusing me.Thanks.

Comment: @Animorv no problem. I figured as much. Just as a pro-tip:  I usually find direct proofs are easier to get the concept because they make the inequalities more obvious conceptually, whereas induction definitely is true, but sometimes muddies where the stuff is really coming from. In any case, happy you got it. Cheers.